# To what corresponds 2 and 3 in ResNet-152 (3×) and ResNet-152 (2×)

Tags: tensorflow, unsupervised-learning, resnet

I use Resnet-50 and ResNet-152 to implement my code,
I read this:

> We also note that ResNet-152 (3×+SK) is only marginally better than ResNet-152 (2×+SK),

So, I would like to undrestand the main difference between ResNet-152 (3×) and ResNet-152 (2×), meaning what corresponds 2 and 3 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

3x and 2x both mean "width". Larger width corresponds to higher number of parameters, meaning that more computations are performed.

According to [this paper](https://deepai.org/publication/big-self-supervised-models-are-strong-semi-supervised-learners) (Table 1), ResNet-152 (3×+SK) has 795 million parameters, while ResNet-152 (2×+SK) has only 354 million parameters (i.e. twice less). However, in terms of accuracy both perform almost equally.

If I were to choose between the two models, I would prefer the smaller one – ResNet-152 (2×+SK).

Answer (score 0):

When I find this :

Total params: 63,090,563
Trainable params: 4,719,619
Non-trainable params: 58,370,944

It's 2× or 3×  ??